# Will initialization of static vector using a function give memory leak?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks

I got the code below. It compiles fine.

```
class A
{
public:
  static std::vector<int> vInt;
  static std::vector<int> Foo()
  {
    std::vector<int> tmp;

    // EDIT: in the real application the values
    // inserted in the vector depends on the result
    // of other functions being called before Foo()
    tmp.push_back(7);
    tmp.push_back(9);
    return tmp;
  }
};

std::vector<int> A::vInt;

int main()
{
  // .... some code

  A::vInt = A::Foo();

  // .... more code
}
```

But I'm wondering whether it has a memory leak?

I'm thinking that the line:

```
std::vector<int> A::vInt;
```

is constructing a vector (an empty vector).

But that vector is later replaced by the line:

```
  A::vInt = A::Foo();
```

So the first vector will never be destroyed and I have a memory leak.
Is that correct or wrong?

EDIT:
My initial queation didn't mention that in the real application I can't call Foo() from the start. The values returned by Foo() depends on other functions that need to be called first. Sorry for being unclear...

Comment: No leak. The assignment operator takes care of things for you.

Comment: As an aside, you are assigning not initializing. Declaration and definition determine what initialization is performed, in your case default-initialization, which means calling the default-ctor for your example.

Comment: No in your scenario it is harmless (you alter the vector at run time), but it might become troublesome during static initialization if other static objects refer to it (however, even then, you have no memory leak)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a leak, but the code still looks quite convoluted to me. I'd prefer something like this:

```
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    static std::vector<int> vInt;
};

std::vector<int> A::vInt{ 7, 9 };

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

But in general, returning a local vector from a function is entirely safe.

In theory, the compiler the compiler copies or moves the local vector into a temporary, then destroys the local. Then it copies or moves the temporary into the destination and destroys the temporary.

The standard explicitly allows bypassing that though--the compiler can (and most will) pass a reference to the destination to the function. The code in the function will write directly to the destination via that reference, so no copies or moves are done at all.

Still: in this case it's pointless. Just initialize the vector where you define it, and you're done (unless you're using an old compiler that doesn't support this, of course--but in that case, it's better to update the compiler if at all possible, rather than write crappy code to suit an old compiler.

Comment: thanks for your answer and explanation. I can, however, not use the solution proposed. From the start up I don't know what Foo shall return. It depends on the result of some function being called before I call Foo(). Sorry - that wasn't clear in my question. I'll add it as an edit. Thanks.

Comment: The paragraph starting "In theory, ..." I translate to the following pseudo code: `copy/move tmp to temporary; delete tmp; copy/move temporary to A::vInt; delete temporary;` That sounds clear but I'm missing something like a `delete A:vInt` before `copy/move temporary to A::vInt;` I know I'm wrong here :) But how/when do the memory for the original vector get released. Can you add an explanation? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you don't have to worry about leaks unless you use the `new` operator. Since you do no dynamic allocation (on the heap), nothing will be leaked; everything on the stack will be taken care of by deterministic destruction.

Comment: The comment about the stack does not apply here: `static` variables are allocated in static storage, which is neither on the stack, nor on the heap. Static storage is defined within the executable and allocated by the system when it loads the program code into memory.

Answer (score 1):

There's no leak since you are using `std::vector`. The standard library takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is will be no leak in your code. output returned by the Foo() will be overwritten at the same address of A:: vInt.
Check below the Valgrind output which also suggests there is no leaks:

`==25088== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 1)
==25088== malloc/free: in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
Write failed: Cannot allocate memoryrees, 20 bytes allocated.
Amits-MacBook-Pro:~ kamal$ ected errors, rerun with: -v
==25088== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible.`